# mysql column fills decimals with zeros at the end

Tags: mysql

I need to store decimals in a mysql column. They have completeley differnet lengths. For example:

```
1.47853 or 0.934
```

At the moment the column fills the decimal with zeros at the end.

```
1.47853000 or 0.93400000
```

This is the mysql table:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: You seem to be confusing data storage with data retrieval and display. That said, for further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In decimal fields, you can specify in the data type how many decimal places you want. If you instead use the float or double data types you don't need to specify how many digits are after the decimal and instead, the field just accepts whatever is given to it as long as it's within the constraints of the datatype.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html

So if I want a field that can have a max value of 9999.999 with no zeros after then I would make the datatype as "DECIMAL (7,3)".

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html

In your example if I did the field datatype as "DOUBLE" then the values would display as 1.47853 and 0.934. If they didn't it would just be a visual results displaying setingg that needs to be tweaked to round the numbers off.

Comment: Thanks. The change to "Double" made it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 column_name  DECIMAL(P,D);
```

In the syntax above:

1. **P:** precision that represents the number of significant digits. The range of P is 1 to 65.
2. **D:** scale that that represents the number of digits after the decimal point. The range of D is 0 and 30.

> MySQL requires that D is less than or equal to (<=) P.

Try the below

```
PriceRandomValue DECIMAL(8,2);
```